# $\psi ( \frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{6})$ and calculating problems?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I ran into a problem, $u=\psi (x,t)$ be a solution of partial deferential equation with following condition on boundary, how we reach the value of $\psi ( \frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{6})$?

> $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$     $- \infty < x < \infty, t>0$
>
> $u(x,0)=\sin{x}$
>
> $u_t(x,0)=\cos{x}$

Comment: You know that $u(t,x)=f(x+t)+g(x-t)$? And what is $sinxx$? $\sin(x)·x$?

Comment: @LutzL sorry now seems fine.

Comment: So you get to solve $f(x)+g(x)=\sin(x)$, $f'(x)-g'(x)=\cos(x)$ which has a surprisingly simple solution.

Comment: @LutzL i get stuck in it. I have the last answer but I couldn't find how my Teacher reach to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unrestricted wave equation has the general solution 
$$
u(t,x)=f(x+t)+g(x−t)
$$
with twice differentiable functions $f$ and $g$. 
This follows from a coordinate change as in $u(t,x)=v(x+t,x-t)$ and concluding that the initial wave equation is equivalent to $\partial_1\partial_2 v(y_1,y_2)=0$.

Evaluating the initial conditions leads to
\begin{align}
f(x)+g(x)&=\sin x\\
f'(x)-g'(x)&=\cos x\\
\implies
f(x)-g(x)&=\sin(x)+C
\end{align}
This leads to the conclusion that $g(x)$ is a constant function that can be absorbed into $f(x)$, so that all together
$$
u(t,x)=\sin(t+x)
$$

Comment: my last answer is $ \sqrt {3} / 2$ !

Comment: That looks right. But remember that you should be able to defend all of the solution steps when asked.

Comment: is it possible make it more clear ?

Comment: This is a difficult question since it depends on what for *you* "clear" is. I.e., the state of your knowledge.

Comment: If i didnt waste your valuable time, please show how we reach to last answer? thanks for learning.

Comment: You do not waste my time, I just do not know what you mean with "how we reach to last answer". I thought you did the calculation $\sin(\pi/2+\pi/6)=\sin(2\pi/3)=\sqrt3/2$.

Comment: thankssssssssssssss.  thanks so much, sorry I Get it. would you please add it to answer. +1.